# My Perl Script runs a system command, I want the output as a string for the rest of the script, how can this be accomplished?

Tags: perl, system

For example if my script was the following:

```
#! /bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

system('echo schwifty')
```

-how could I get the output on my terminal (schwifty) into a string that I could continue on with my script using?

NOTE: "echo" is just given as an example I'm using other commands that print to the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To capture output of an external command, use backticks or `qx`:

```
my $output = qx{echo schwifty};
die unless $output =~ /schw/;
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-line system calls such as `ls` I tend to use an @array to store the output. More flexible than a variable when there are lots of lines to process.

Very similar to choroba's example but expanded a little further.

```
my @output = qx{ ls -l };

foreach my $line ( @output )
{
    # process each $line here
    print "$line";
}
```